# Not working css calc() in FireFox 29.0.1

Tags: css, firefox, css-calc

```
 <style>
    .mapstyle {
          height: 100%;
          height: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px);
          height: -moz-calc(100% - 60px);
          height: calc(100% - 60px);
          margin-left: 300px;
     }
 </style>

<div style="margin:0 auto; position:relative; text-align: left; width: 100%;">
 <div style"width:100%;"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
 <div style="width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 0;">test</div>
 <div id="map" class="mapstyle">
      <script>....
              var map = L.map('map').setView([57.3, 29.4],).setMaxBounds(bounds);
              ...//Leafletjs.com
      </script>
 </div>
</div>
```

function calc() in css not working in firefox 29.0.1, other browsers is working.

Comment: Please post a *complete* code example and explain what "not working" means exactly. And why are you defining height four times? Also, a jsFiddle.net example might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change first div

```
position:absolute; height:100%
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dxn5d/2/

Comment: and your header code must be have = 
<div style="width:100%;"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>

Comment: Could you explain? What was wrong in the first place and why?

Comment: @SepehrM  `position:absolute;` was what was missing from the original code